# What is the simplest loading screen to show while the http request is not finished?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loading

At the moment, i show only network activity indicator until the request is finished with:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

What UI element or screen should i show with some text ("loading data") until the request is done and i can show the received data? 
What is the usual way in iOs for this ?

Comment: This really depends. Do you want to prevent the user from doing anything?

Comment: Yes, nothing is allowed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [MBProgressHUD](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-heads-up-display-with-mbprogresshud.html), or the like. This is quite common in cases where no user input is allowed. Otherwise, if it's in the background, your networkActivityIndicator method should suffice.